# Apache Ambari and how to check Ambari services status

Tags: linux, hadoop

**How to verify service statuses via Ambari?**

For example, I want to check in Ambari if the HDFS service is stopped or has been `STARTED`.

Until now I use the following syntax in order to check the service status:

```
ENDPOINT="http://${SERVER}:${PORT}/api/v1/clusters/${CLUSTERNAME}/services/${SERVICE}"
curl --silent -u admin:admin -X GET ${ENDPOINT}?fields=ServiceInfo | grep state
```

But I do not get the output about stopped/`STARTED`, as you can see from commands results. What we only get is `INSTALLED`:

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 100  1207  100  1207    0     0  28158      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 28738
 Checking HIVE
 {
    "href" : "http://master02.ipmassanalyt41.com:8080/api/v1/clusters/HDP26/services/HIVE?fields=ServiceInfo",
 "ServiceInfo" : {
   "cluster_name" : "HDP26",
    "credential_store_enabled" : "true",
   "credential_store_supported" : "true",
   "maintenance_state" : "OFF",
   "service_name" : "HIVE",
      "state" : "INSTALLED"
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The state `INSTALLED` indicates that the relevant service is installed but not started.

Quoting from the [Ambari REST API Doc](https://github.com/apache/ambari/blob/trunk/ambari-server/docs/api/v1/service-resources.md),

> INSTALLED The service has been installed successfully but is not currently running.

You may need to start/restart the service.

If the service is running normally, the state will be `STARTED`.